# Obtain the "pretty" hostname in bash

Tags: fedora, hostname

On my Fedora 19 system, I am able to change the system hostname with `hostnamectl`. This allows me to set several things, such as the static (normal) hostname, as well as a "pretty" hostname.

Is there a simple command that retrieves the pretty hostname, from a bash prompt?

`hostname` returns the static hostname, and the man page shows no options to recover the pretty one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per `man hostnamectl`:

> The static host name is stored in /etc/hostname, see hostname(5) for more information. The pretty host name,
>        chassis type and icon name are stored in /etc/machine-info, see machine-id(5).

Therefore, if you have set a pretty hostname using the command

`hostnamectl set-hostname --pretty YourHostname`

you can retrieve it using a tool like `awk`:

```
awk -F= '/PRETTY/ {print $2}' /etc/machine-info
```

Comment: @Evgeny Vereschagin Piping awk to sed is an ugly as it is redundant: `awk -F= '/PRETTY/ {gsub(/"/,"");print $2}' /etc/os-release` is simpler...

Comment: I agree. But that doesn't work with my example. Try `hostnamectl set-hostname --pretty '"MyPretty\\Name"'`, `awk -F= '/PRETTY/ {gsub(/"/,"");print $2}' /etc/machine-info`. The result is wrong.

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin Who would ever set `'"MyPretty\\Name"'` as a *pretty* name?

Comment: well. this is an extreme case. try `sudo hostnamectl --pretty set-hostname "Lennart's Laptop"` (example from the manpage) on Fedora 19. `awk -F= '/PRETTY/ {gsub(/"/,"");print $2}'` prints wrong result `Lennart\'s Laptop`.

Comment: I don't like `awk ... | sed ...` too. the `sed`-only solution: `sed 's/^[^=]*=//; s/^"//; s/"$//; s/\\\(.\)/\1/g' /etc/machine-info`

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin Yes: my point is that piping awk to sed is *always* wrong. If you want to post a sed answer, then you are welcome to do that...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433245/5132 explains why `awk` and `sed` are poor ideas for this type of configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

`hostnamectl --pretty` will directly print the pretty hostname out. Tested on systemd version 239.

Comment: It does not work for me on v241 on Debian 10.  I think you have to set it with that command first then it will show up.

Comment: Yes, pretty hostname is.really a usersapce thing, systemd use its own definition

Answer (score 0):

For my system, `hostnamectl --static` was the ticket. It is worth first running `hostnamectl` to see how your system is set up. From there, you can determine what steps make the most sense to make it pretty.