# Store a value from os-release text file after an = sign individually

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to store the value of os-version from the command `cat /etc/os-release`.
The output of cat /etc/os-release is

```
VERSION="4.4"
ID="someId"
ID_LIKE="someIdLike"
```

I want a shell command to store the version "4.4" into a variable without apostrophes or the text "VERSION". So far what I have done is

```
variable==`grep 'VERSION' /etc/os-release
```

which gives me variable=" VERSION="4.4"" and I just want the numerical value of the version which would be just 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

The `os-release` manual on Ubuntu states that the `/etc/os-release` file should contain simple variable assignments compatible with the shell and that one should be able to source the file:

> The basic file format of `os-release` is a newline-separated list of
> environment-like shell-compatible variable assignments. It is possible to source
> the configuration from shell scripts [...]

```bsh
$ ( . /etc/os-release && printf '%s\n' "$VERSION" )
20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
```

Above, I'm sourcing the file in a subshell to avoid polluting my interactive environment.  In a shell script, you might not care too much about that.  After sourcing the file, I print the value of the `VERSION` variable.

The bare version number, without the patch release number, is available in the `VERSION_ID` variable on my system. Still, you could get it with the patch release included from the `VERSION` variable by removing everything after the first space with a standard variable expansion.

```bsh
$ ( . /etc/os-release && printf '%s\n' "${VERSION%% *}" "$VERSION_ID" )
20.04.3
20.04
```

On your system, since the `VERSION` variable seems to contain the string `4.4` and nothing else, you could source the file and use `"$VERSION"` without further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lsb_release` to get the release number:

```
variable=$(lsb_release -rs)
```

`man lsb_release`:

```
-r, --release       displays release number of distribution.
-s, --short   displays all of the above information in short output format.
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the above answers as they were really helpful, but I found another solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498788 which states that we can store the value from `os-release` as

```
VERSION=$(grep -oP '(?<=^VERSION_ID=).+' /etc/os-release | tr -d '"')
echo $VERSION
```